# Access vba bound form validation rule "impossible'"

Tags: vba, forms

I have a bound form, I'm using the event Form_BeforeUpdate to check some validations rules, one of them has been driving me crazy for days, here's the situation: in my job, the employees can take 30 days of working days paid vacation with the option to split it up to 03 periods of 10 days, in the form each record represents one of these periods of vacation and there are 02 important fields [Start_Date] and [End_Date]. I would like that for each record of an employee, let´s say Jonh, access counts the days of the current record and how many days he already has recorded and refuses if the total of the days were greater than 30, of course with the cancel=true e me.undo. Please help me.

Comment: Are the 10 days per period mandatory? 1 period = 10 days, 2 periods = 20 days?

Comment: In fact, it's an option, as long the employee doesn´t surpass 30 days and 3 periods, he or she can choose any combination of the days, for instance, 10+10+10 or 5 + 12+13 or 20+10 and so on.